# When deriving keys from passwords, should I store the key or use the key to encrypt?

Tags: encryption, passwords

The following quote has made me question what I thought I knew.

> "Now consider bcrypt. It uses Blowfish to encrypt a magic string, using
>   a key "derived" from the password. Later, when a user enters a
>   password, the key is derived again, and if the ciphertext produced by
>   encrypting with that key matches the stored ciphertext, the user is
>   authenticated. The ciphertext is stored in the "password" table, but
>   the derived key is never stored."

I was under the assumption that you store the hash of the salted password.

```
    Where:
    - KDF = a key derivation function such as pbkdf2 or bcrypt
    - salt = a unique 16 byte salt
    - password = the password the user entered
    - saltedPassword = the password appended to the salt
    - hashedSaltedPassword = KDF(saltedPassword)
    - USER = a database table where usernames and passwords are stored<br

USER.Password = hashedSaltedPassword
USER.PasswordSalt = salt
```

Is this correct or am I way off?

Comment: The hash of the salted password is the cipher text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quote basically describes how to use bcrypt (which is a [key-derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function)) as the basis of a salted hash function.  That function's inputs are a password and a salt, and its output is a hash value.  That hash value *happens to be* the ciphertext produced by encryping a constant string with a bcrypt-derived key, but you don't care about that:  you're just using it as a hash value.

So yes, you *do* store the hash of the salted password.

Comment: Thanks Wyzard, I was pretty sure I had it right, but I have no formal training, thought maybe I missed a step.